# C++ interface design: Private virtuals

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, class-design, virtual-functions

Say I have an interface class A (class with only pure virtual functions). Also, I have a concrete class B, which holds a weak pointer to A, and calls methods on it.

There is strong coupling between classes A and B. Basically I expect only class B will call methods on class A.

Does it make sense to declare all methods on A, private (pure) virtual and make class B its friend. The classes implementing A, will be free to change the access of the functions they implement as part of inheriting A.  It seems appropriate for the use case but I haven't seen it used before.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense, and it addresses one design issue, but it raises another one (which you might either consider minor or not).

In Sutter and Alexandrescu's [C++ Coding Standards](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321113586) there's a guideline [39. Consider making virtual functions nonpublic, and public functions nonvirtual](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/c-coding-standards/0321113586/ch40.html). This makes sense. Say you have

```
class interface {
public:
    virtual void bar();
};
```

then you realize that all `bar`s have something in common: maybe you want to validate arguments passed to them (if they take arguments), or log calls to all of them. Because of this, the guideline is to split it into

```
class interface {
public:
    void bar() { bar_(); }

protected:
    virtual void bar_();
};
```

I.e., a public non-virtual method calling a non-public virtual one. The public one is the only gateway to the virtual one.

The problem is that this is the only gateway until you introduce `friend`. Then, you have no control, and the external class can call `bar_` directly, circumventing it.

---

In your case, you could consider the following, therefore:

Say the class to which you want to grant access is `foo`, and the interface class is `interface`. Write another class `interface_accessor`, which will be the gateway:

```
class foo;

class interface;

class interface_accessor {
private:
     static void bar(interface &i);

     friend class foo;                                                  
};
```

Note that `interface_accessor` is a friend of `foo`.

Now, make `interface` a friend of `interface_accessor`, but not of `foo`:

```
class interface {
private:
    virtual void bar_() {}

    friend class interface_accessor;
};
```

Finally, implement `interface_accessor`:

```
void interface_accessor::bar(interface &i) {
    i.bar_();
}
```

Comment: But this is probably not an issue here, since I plan on declaring "all" methods on A(interface) private and virtual. It's just that I haven't really seen this pattern used before. Note that the interface in my case only has a single client. This tight coupling is probably what makes the problem different.

Comment: The fact that all methods of A are virtual is orthogonal to the guideline. It just means that the entire class is composed of pairs of public nonvirtual + virtual nonpublic. The problem is that your `friend` makes this moot, which is what I tried to address in my answer. As to the single client - note that it is the sole `friend` of `interface_accessor`.